# using : LinearLayout layout = super.root inside cordova (phonegap) project have error?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using google service in cordova (phonegap) project to show google Admob but will be out error when written as LinearLayout layout = super.root in onCreate. What do will you know the cause? Following error content. 
Description Resource Path Location Type 
root CAN BE not resolved or not IS A field

Please help me ? thank you very much !

bellow is source code in main activity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import minigames.flappy.R;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity

{

    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    private AdView mAdView ;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

        loadUrl(launchUrl);


        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID );
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        LinearLayout layout = super.root; // error here
        layout.addView(mAdView);    
        layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solved your question? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

In new Cordova (cordova CLI 5.0  and cordova-android v4.0), the layout is not LinearLayout any more. The webview is set as content view directly.

See the apache cordova-andorid source code:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java#L181

To use Google AdMob in your project, you don't have to write java code, as you can use existing and mature cordova plugin. You can easily present banner and full screen interstitial Ad with 2-3 javascript code.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Sample javascript code:

```
// it will display smart banner at top center, using the default options
if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner, 
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER, 
    autoShow: true } );
```

To see a working demo, try:

```
[sudo] npm install plugin-verify -g
plugin-verify cordova-plugin-admobpro android
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't use cordova-plugin-admobpro, i use google play service, you can help me sample code for this one.

Comment: As the cordova webview is set as content view, it's not in a linear layout anymore. To display the banner, you have to create a relative layout or linearlayout by your own.